# Grub does not recognize password

Tags: grub, opensuse, dual-boot

I'm running Grub .97 with an OpenSuSE 11.2 and Windows XP installation.  I configure the grub password in OpenSuSE 11.2 via the `Boot Loader` module.  However, when I type in the password in grub, during bootup, I simply get a `Failed` message.  I have tried about three or four different passwords.  I can boot up, I just can't use the password to edit anything about grub.

I have also tried setting the grub password via the command line by typing `grub` to go to the interactive menu, typing `md5crypt`, typing my password, and copying the hashed password to the menu.lst file.  Still no luck when I enter the password.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're typing the password right? If you aren't using a US keyboard layout, have you declared your layout to Grub?

Comment: @Gilles, good question and of course the obvious one to be asked.  To ensure that typing the password wasn't an issue, I changed to a much simpler one on a temporary basis.  Yes, I am using the keyboard layout.

Comment: U.S. keyboard layout that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=1b83314b1bdb2fccb952b5aede88fbd0&p=2620111&postcount=7).  If I use the `md5crypt` command to generate my password, I need to enter `--md5` between my `password` and the encrypted password.  Now this works.

So, before the `title` entries in my `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file I have the line with a password.  This now reads

`password  --md5   encrypted_password`.

Based on my experience, it appears that setting the password for the Boot Loader via YaST does not work correctly for OpenSuSE 11.2.  I have not yet checked to see if adding a `--md5` to the encrypted password provided by YaST would cause it to work, I've only tried the `md5crypt` method with this.